# How can I redirect my homepage to my main domain using Django?

Tags: django, url

I am trying to redirect my homepage URL path, https://www.va-glazing.com/home/ URL, to my main domain, which is https://www.va-glazing.com.

I am hosting my site on PythonAnywhere and got the domain from godaddy.com.

Comment: Just change your the url path where it says `home/` to `''`.

Comment: hm on the views page or url?

Comment: Can you please add the template file and url.py file ?

Comment: got it to work, thank you!